# Descending induction variant(s)

Tags: logic, induction

> Let $a,b$ be two natural numbers such that $a\leq b$, and let $P(n)$
>   denote some statement such that the following conjunction holds:
>
> $$P(b)\ \land\ (\forall n)(n\in \mathbb{N}\ \land\ a\leq n<b\ \land\
>  P(n+1)\implies P(n)).$$
>
> Then, $(\forall n)(n\in\mathbb{N}\ \land\ a\leq n\leq b\implies
>  P(n))$.

Are there variants of this in which one can replace $P(n+1)$ in the inductive hypothesis with something like $P(m)$ for all $m>n$? And, generally speaking, can this technique only be carried out over some finite interval of $\mathbb{N}$?

Thank you in advance.